# React range slider giving issue on mobile view when start dragging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rangeslider

I am facing a very unexpected issue in react range slider, its working fine on web but when i go to mobile view using chrome developer tool and start dragging it its giveng me this weird error, check the screenshot, please:

[image: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined]

this is the package i am using in my project: https://codepen.io/davidchin/pen/GpNvqw

my range Component is here

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import InputRange from 'react-input-range';

export default class RangeSlider extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: { min: 2, max: 10 },
            disabled: false
        };
    }
render() {

        return (
            <InputRange
                maxValue={20}
                minValue={0}
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={value => this.setState({ value })}
            />
        );
    }
    }
```

Comment: If you can create a codepan which reproduce the issue, it will be easier to investigate.. Is this happening on mobile devices too or only on the chrome "emulator"?

Comment: Well as i said its a really weird and i solved this accidently :D its giving error on local enviroment only. i uploaded my files to server its working fine now..